# Custom CakePHP order by clause for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, autocomplete

I have a database of locations the user can select from by typing and autocompletion. In my CakePHP controller, I do this:

```
    $locations = $this->Location->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Location.name like' => '%'.$term.'%'),
        'fields' => array('Location.id', 'Location.name', 'Region.name'),
        'order' => array(
            array('Location.name = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($term).'"'
                => 'desc'),
            'Location.name'
        ),
        'limit' => 10,
        'recursive' => 1,
    ));
```

It works perfectly fine, but it feels like a hack, and I'd rather not escape SQL literals myself.

The first order by clause is needed since a perfect match might otherwise not make it to the top of the alphabetically sorted list.

I considered moving the equality-test into a virtual field, but I don't feel it's a very elegant solution when the $term is dynamic.

How do I implement this in a better way?

Comment: This looks fine to me. Think about how you would write it if you had to write the SQL longhand, then you'll have a measure of how elegant it is. If it works, leave it.

Comment: Does Cake not automatically escape ALL the sql?  I would've guessed that it would escape your order by clause as well as everything else.

Comment: Actually, I realized it's not a search engine, but just simple autocompletition, so the *real* solution is to search for any name *beginning* with the term ($term.'%') instead. Then the order by exact match isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the structure of your query is written this is fine.

In regards to having to escape SQL yourself, this is [from the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/153/Data-Sanitization):

> CakePHP already protects you against
>   SQL Injection if you use CakePHP's ORM
>   methods (such as find() and save())
>   and proper array notation (ie.
>   array('field' => $value)) instead of
>   raw SQL. For sanitization against XSS
>   its generally better to save raw HTML
>   in database without modification and
>   sanitize at the time of
>   output/display.